# how to download and load a script file?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, typescript

following a list of [tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQNUhLTQtdw), I need to create a TS file. I have followed everything in this tutorial (and all the previous 16, on creating a calendar using orchard cms)

So if you look at **4.49** on the video where Ron explains to go and download the `JQuery` (which is needed as a ref). So he tells us (but doesnt show us) to download the jquery.d.ts file from [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery) and then insert it into the project.

This is all fine but I cant find no where to download it.
If i click on `jquery.d.ts` a text document type format displays the file on screen. So I'v tried copying the text to a file and saving it locally, to the location he mentions on the video.

But this throws over 50 errors...so im guessing this isn't correct. can anyone tell me how to correctly load this file in my project?

Thanks

---

EDIT

ok so thanks for the help so far guys...I didnt realise clicking raw downloaded the doc. so its d/l and placed into the same location as the tutorial and I am getting a number of errors.....for example

```
async?: boolean; //boolean is flagging up as: any: the name boolean does not exist in the current scope.
interface JQueryXHR extends XMLHttpRequest, JQueryPromise<any> { //JQueryPromise does not exist in the current scope

//then there are a number of functions:
interface JQueryGenericPromise<T
interface JQueryPromise<T> {
interface JQueryDeferred<
etc...//all saying duplicate identifier interface expected ;


declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;//the name JQueryStatic does not exist in the current scope
```

bear in mind this is downloaded as it is. I have no changed anything.
thank you for any replies guys

Comment: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/raw/master/jquery/jquery-tests.ts

Comment: thanks for that I tried that but it throws different errors. then I checked it against the online document and they are completely different?

Comment: that is very strange. I hope that you find it. Good luck

Comment: the reason you are getting those error are probably because you don't have the rest of the project included there, see the edit to my answer

Comment: The reason you are getting this; `JQueryStatic does not exist in the current scope` is probably because you didn't download the entire project. were those two files the only files you downloaded?
Those are only two files in a much larger project scope, therefore you will get errors of files not being found

Comment: ok thanks il download the entire project now and give it a go but that wasnt mentioned in the tutorial...he just said the one fiel

Comment: so do I download the entire project then insert the whole project, as an existing one? or d/l the project and only insert the file I need?

Comment: I tried insertin the project as an existing one. but there is no csproj file in it?

Comment: if you watch the tutorial @ 4.49 Ron only needs the one file....why would I need more? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQNUhLTQtdw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GitHub you can hit the "Raw" button, which normally downloads the file.

https://raw.github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

Failing that, you can copy and paste the text into a file and then save it as jquery.d.ts

If you still have errors, share them and we'll help you to fix them. The most likely would be if you are using an older version of TypeScript - the jQuery definition is updated for TypeScript 0.9

UPDATE

It is pretty much what I thought - the `boolean` type is new to TypeScript 0.9 and replaces the `bool` type from TypeScript 0.8.

You need to either...

A. Get [the latest version of TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) - it will then recognise the `boolean` type

Or

B. Get [an older version of the jQuery definition file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/de9c457a11dfa7bb31cd1884f250dba07c52e991/jquery/jquery.d.ts) from before it was updated for 0.9

Comment: ok thanks didnt realise 'raw' downloaded the file...but still getting errors il post them to the original Q

Answer (score 0):

If you're sent to github and you see file names on the page, they are usually links and if clicked. . .you can save the destination or the browser will ask you where to save it, 
but I think, for what you're looking for; you need to install an [subversion](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) client and signup with github so you can send a pull request, and the code will be imported into your project

EDIT:
there's a button on the [parent page](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) that says 'download zip' if you just want to download the project

Comment: so i've created an account with github but when i click the filename on the page it still brings me to the a page containing a text type document of the file

Comment: @John you have to install an svn client; http://maymay.net/blog/2009/02/24/how-to-use-git-svn-as-the-only-subversion-client-youll-need/
and then point it to the repository link that you were given

Comment: @John If you go to the project folder, there's a download button, see my edit

Comment: please see edit of original Q, i got it downloaded but the file is throwing errors