# downloaded a typescript file but it is throwing a lot of errors — how can I resolve?

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, typescript

If you skip to 5.17 of this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQNUhLTQtdw you will hear Ron explaining to ONLY download the jquery.d.ts file, and import it into the relevant folder of your project.

When I do this the jquery.d.ts file throws a lot of errors about things not existing in the current scope. So I figured I am missing relevant files from the same project (although the video DOES MENTION you only need the one).

I've downloaded the entire zip file made a list of all the errors so for e.g. where JQueryPromise: does not exist in the current scope, I have searched the entire project for all references to JQueryPromise, and added the remaining files to the project.

This had no effect, so I added all the files manually to the folder in the project.
This still has no effect.

I was looking to add the entire project, but all the files are .ts. and .js.

My Q is how can I resolve this? why has it worked for the tutorial and not for me?

I may mention whether it has any affect or not but he is using VS2012 and downloaded TypeScript, I am using VS2010 and used the following link to install TypeScript in VS2010
[How Can I Install TypeScript with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510511/how-can-i-install-typescript-with-visual-studio-2010)

does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are compiling using TypeScript 0.8 and the file is written in TypeScript 0.9 and there are breaking changes.

Full answer here:

[how to download and load a script file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236105/how-to-download-and-load-a-script-file)